# Swift primitive data types source code (e.g. UInt64, Float ...)

Tags: swift, types

I want to implement an "Int512" type with integer literals support and all the stuff standard types (like Int64) have. There's not much docs / info over the Internet on this matter, so I figured that the best thing is to dig the sources and do it in the same way.

I have checked out https://github.com/apple/swift but having difficulties with finding there Int64 implementation.
Is that the right thing to look in? And if so, maybe someone knows where the sources for primitive types are.

Comment: Why would you need that? Have you tried using the Swift native `Decimal`?
 type

Comment: Anyway take a look at the `BinaryInteger` protocol https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Integers.swift and IntegerTypes https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/IntegerTypes.swift.gyb

Comment: @LeoDabus I need a precise result value (multiplication of 2 64-digit integers) + want to understand how that stuff works under the hood by doing it myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "explicit" Int64 implementation. Since most numeric types are somehow similar, the swift source files are being generated by a tool named *gyb* (generate your boilerplate), to be found here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/utils/gyb.py

This tools reads .gyb files and creates the source code. In your case, its the file
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/IntegerTypes.swift.gyb

This could be good starting point; just check for 'Int32' and do the appropriate stuff for 'Int512' :-)

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that's exactly what I've been looking for!